# how to fetch data from drop down to another drop down using array

Tags: codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#org_id").change(function() {

            var org_id = $('#org_id').val();
            var id = parseInt(org_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Frontdoor/get_parameter_value",
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {

                    html1 = '';
                    html2 = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i = i + 1) {
                        html1 += '<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].parameter_name + '</option>';
                        html2 += '<option value="' + response.data[i].id + '">' + response.data[i].p_answer + '</option>';
                    }

                    $('.que_ans').html(html1);
                    $('.que_ans').trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $('.que_ans1').html(html2);
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: why it is not worked?